# how to compare and concatenate same lines in huge csv files in bash?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, lines

i have the following .csv files(huge in size~hundreds of MB to GB, several columns~20, not sorted, delimited by ","):

```
name1,address1,town1,zip1,....,category1
name2,address2,town2,zip2,....,category2
name3,address3,town3,zip3,....,category3_1
name3,address3,town3,zip3,....,category3_2
name3,address3,town3,zip3,....,category3_3
name4,address4,town4,zip4,....,category4_1
name4,address4,town4,zip4,....,category4_2
name4,address4,town4,zip4,....,category4_3
name4,address4,town4,zip4,....,category4_4
name5,address5,town5,zip5,....,category5
```

i need to concatenate lines to only one, if they has the same lines and differs only in categories and put those categories to the last column with the ";" delimiter, e.g.:

```
name1,address1,town1,zip1,....,category1
name2,address2,town2,zip2,....,category2
name3,address3,town3,zip3,....,category3_1;category3_2;category3_3
name4,address4,town4,zip4,....,category4_1;category4_2;category4_3;category4_4
name5,address5,town5,zip5,....,category5
```

i tried it with **while read ...; do read ... done < $file** ,but this is only reading every file by 2lines and doesn't compare every line. also tried to save the category information to array and create merged category column, but at some line script just stops parsing it the way i want.
it would be great to finish this in **awk** or **sed**, because **read** is REALLY slow when reading big files with a lot of columns, but if there's better way to do this with other language i'll be okay with it.
thanks a LOT!

Comment: How many of the fields need to be identical for the records to be "the same". I mean, you are showing 4 fields must be the same in your example before categories can be merged, but imply there are others. Do the others need to match too?

Comment: i removed the duped lines, so the whole line is identical(didnt want to spam whole line:]) when at least name field is identical. then identical lines have only categories different. i need these different categories to be merged with delimiter. does that make sense?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I count `5` fields before, in the sample, but if else, you could change the number in my GNU sed sample ;-)

Comment: What if `name1` is at `address1` AND `address2`? Do we merge the categories?

Comment: What if `name1,address1,town1,zip1` is in line 1 but line 2 contains `name1,address1,town1,zip1` but differs in say the ninth (unshown) field? Do we merge categories then?

Comment: `name1` cant contain `address2`, lines differs in categories, which is last column/field and should be merged...
there are some cases that line can contain more information as i mentioned in edit. so yes is the answer to your second question.

Comment: Please don't change meaning of question once they was ansered: ask another question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two answers:

**Shell + sed**

You could use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) for this (particular) case:

( **Hmm, too quick!** I was wrong!

```
$ sed -e ':;N;s/^\(\([^,]\+,\)\{5\}\)\(.*\)*\n\1/\1\3;/;t' file.csv
```

)

```
$ sed -e ':a;$!N;s/^\(\([^,]\+,\)\{5\}\)\(.*\)*\n\1/\1\3;/;ta;P;D;$!ba' file.csv
```

For retrieving number of columns (-1) aka number of separators:

```
read line <file.csv
cols="${line//,}"
cols=$[${#line}-${#cols}]

sed -e "
    :a;
     $!N;
     s/^\(\([^,]\+,\)\{$cols\}\)\(.*\)*\n\1/\1\3;/;
     ta;
     P;
     D;
     $!ba
  " file.csv

name1,address1,town1,zip1,....,category1
name2,address2,town2,zip2,....,category2
name3,address3,town3,zip3,....,category3_1;category3_2;category3_3
name4,address4,town4,zip4,....,category4_1;category4_2;category4_3;category4_4
name5,address5,town5,zip5,....,category5
```

**Last field only!**

There is a simpler way based on *last comma*:

```
sed -e ":;$!N;s/^\(.*,\)\([^,]*\)*\n\1/\1\2;/;t;P;D;$!b" file.csv
```

(For whipping unwanted *CR* at end of lines:

```
sed -e ':;$!N;s/\o015//g;s/^\(.*,\)\([^,]*\)*\n\1/\1\2;/;t;P;D;$!b'
```

)

**Pure bash (no fork)**

This could be done using pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (this work fine using [dash](/questions/tagged/dash) and [busybox](/questions/tagged/busybox) too!), but maybe more suitable for small files:

```
while read line;do
    if [ "${line%,*}" = "${last%,*}" ];then
        last="$last;${line##*,}"
    else
        echo "$last"
        last="$line"
    fi
done < file.csv
echo "$last"

name1,address1,town1,zip1,....,category1
name2,address2,town2,zip2,....,category2
name3,address3,town3,zip3,....,category3_1;category3_2;category3_3
name4,address4,town4,zip4,....,category4_1;category4_2;category4_3;category4_4
name5,address5,town5,zip5,....,category5
```

**Note:** there is no need to know number of columns, because this is based on *last comma*.

Comment: based on the number of columns(where the category entry is located), which number do i have to change in sed? it is in the last column, but the number of columns can change in each .csv file. ty!

Comment: The number in my sed sample is the `5`. You could print this number by: `echo $[$(head -n1 file|wc -c)-$(head -n1 file|tr -d ,|wc -c)]`

Comment: both of the solutions partially works... but there is a small problem with carriage return "\r" char at the end of the lines.. i can get rid of it through line=$(echo $line | tr -d '\r') is there a faster way? because echo is the most time consuming part of the scripts. and what about this char in sed?

Comment: You could use `<(tr -d \\r <file.csv)`  in place of `file.csv` , or you could use  `s/\r//g;` in [tag:sed] (after `N;`)... or even `${line//$'\r'}` in [tag:bash].

Comment: the last `sed` with wiping of the _CR_ works at least with my first question. is there a way to store line based on the `_1` category?