# advanced concatenation of lines based on the specific number of compared columns in csv

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, compare

this is the question based on the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832525/how-to-compare-and-concatenate-same-lines-in-huge-csv-files-in-bash) solved problem.
i have the following type of .csv files(they aren't all sorted!, but the structure of columns is the same):

```
name1,address1,town1,zip1,email1,web1,,,,category1
name2,address2,town2,zip2,email2,,,,,category2
name3,address3,town3,zip3,email3,,,,,category3_1
name3,address3,town3,zip3,,,,,,category3_2
name3,address3,town3,zip3,,,,,,category3_3
name4,address4,town4,zip4,,,,,,category4_1
name4,address4,town4,zip4,email4,,,,,category4_2
name4,address4,town4,zip4,email4,,,,,category4_3
name4,address4,town4,zip4,,,,,,category4_4
name5,address5,town5,zip5,,,,,,category5_1
name5,address5,town5,zip5,,web5,,,,category5_2
name6,address6,town6,zip6,,,,,,category6
```

- first 4 records in columns are always populated, other columns are not always, except the last one - category
- empty space between "," delimiter means that there is no data for the particular line or name
- if the nameX doesnt contain addressX but addressY, it is a different record(not the same line) and should not be concatenated

i need the script in **sed** or **awk**, maybe the **bash**(but this solution is little slower on bigger files[hundreds of MB+]), that will take first 4 columns(in this case) compares them and if matched, will merge every category with the ";" delimiter and will keep the structure and the most possible data in other columns of those matched lines of a .csv file:

```
name1,address1,town1,zip1,email1,web1,,,,category1
name2,address2,town2,zip2,email2,,,,,category2
name3,address3,town3,zip3,email3,,,,,category3_1;category3_2;category3_3
name4,address4,town4,zip4,email4,,,,,category4_1;category4_2;category4_3;category4_4
name5,address5,town5,zip5,,web5,,,,category5_1;category5_2
name6,address6,town6,zip6,,,,,,category6
```

if that is not possible, solution could be to retain data from the first line of the duped data(the one with categoryX_1). example:

```
name1,address1,town1,zip1,email1,web1,,,,category1
name2,address2,town2,zip2,email2,,,,,category2
name3,address3,town3,zip3,email3,,,,,category3_1;category3_2;category3_3
name4,address4,town4,zip4,,,,,,category4_1;category4_2;category4_3;category4_4
name5,address5,town5,zip5,,,,,,category5_1;category5_2
name6,address6,town6,zip6,,,,,,category6
```

does the .csv have to be sorted before using the script?

thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/.*/²&³/;H
$ { g
:cat
  s/\(²\([^,]*,\)\{4\}\)\(\([^,]*,\)\{5\}\)\([^³]*\)³\(.*\)\n\1\(\([^,]*,\)\{5\}\)\([^³]*\)³/\1~\3~ ~\7~\5;\9³\6/
  t fields
  b clean
:fields
  s/~\([^,]*\),\([^~]*~\) ~\1,\([^~]*~\)/\1,~\2 ~\3/
  t fields
  s/~\([^,]*\),\([^~]*~\) ~\([^,]*,\)\([^~]*~\)/\1\3~\2 ~\4/
  t fields
  s/~~ ~~//g

  b cat

:clean
  s/.//;s/[²³]//g
  p
  }' YourFile
```

Posix version (so `--posix`with GNU sed) and without sorting your file previously

2 recursive loop after loading the full file in buffer, adding marker for easier manipulation and lot of fun with sed group substitution (hopefully just reach the maximum group available).

1. loop to add category (1 line after the other, needed for next loop on each field) per line and a big sub field temporary structured (2 group of field from the 2 concatened lines. field 5 to 9 are 1 group)
2. ungroup sub field to original place

finaly, remove marker and first new line

Assuming there is no `²³~` character because used as marker (you can use other marker and adapt the script with your new marker)

Note:

- For performance on a hundred MB file, i guess awk will be lot more efficient.
- Sorting the data previoulsy may help certainly in performance reducing amount of data to manipulate after each category loop

Comment: asuming the number of columns will change, which numbers i have to change?
i think 4, 5 and 9? is that right?
thank you!

Comment: another thing - script is almost working flawlessly, it is only duping your group fields 5 to 9... does it have anything to do with the special chars as markers?

Comment: For the number of field, until is is always the same in the file, no problem. Adapt the `\{4\}` and `\{5\}` should be enough. For duping, don't see your result (I test on a AIX) but it is heavily depending of third marker `~` and field separator `,` in this case. It copies content of both line assembled at their relative place. if L1F5=Hello and L2F5=World the result of F5 will be *HelloWorld*

Comment: this is the output what i get:
`name1,address1,town1,zip1,email1,web1,,,,category1
name2,address2,town2,zip2,email2,,,,,category2
name3,address3,town3,zip3,email3,,,,,category3_1;category3_3;category3_2
name4,address4,town4,zip4,email4email4,,,,,category4_1;category4_4;category4_3;category4_2
name5,address5,town5,zip5,,web5,,,,category5_1;category5_2
name6,address6,town6,zip6,,,,,,category6`
can you see the email4 duped? it is the same issue that i get on real data as well...
if it is the problem with the `~` char, which of them should i change for other special char?
runing on ubuntu14.04

Comment: not an issue with `~` :-( this the code i have to change and add a check if data is the same, not duplicate it. What if 2 different info occur like email4_1@lazy.dog and email4_2@brown.fox ?

Comment: Code adapted for this issue. No duplication if field content is the same in both record

Comment: in 99.99% of cases if the email4_1 entry is not empty it will have the same email entry as any other email4_X. there is only chance that one line4 will have email4 entry and the other wont. its the same with other columns(eg. telephone, web, etc.)
i think the wisest idea is only to overwrite it, or overwrite empty with nonempty... if you have enough fantasy and will to make it, but basic overwrite is ok for me!

Comment: one more thing - in real .csv files i have `\r` _CR_ char... to put it away insert `s/\o015//g` after `:cat`
its working great!! many many thanks!

Comment: you could put your s as first command, faster (less char to treat after). If the answer is ok, put sometime a +1 (if your profile allow this)

Comment: i know about that substitution, but thanks... i would definitely like to, but i need 15 reputation to do this +1 thingie. i'll surely do it, when i get enough points

Answer (score 0):

i found, that this particular problem is faster being processed through db...

[SQL - GROUP BY to combine/concat a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/sql-group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column)

db: mysql through wamp